# How to find multiple values for Cake PHP find() method? (IN condition)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

Is there a way to do a find() in CakePHP that converts to an IN condition?  It seems the find() methods just take a single value to search on.

I would like to do something like this:

```
$this->User->findAllById(array(1, 5, 7));
```

which would convert the SQL to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1, 5, 7);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('id' => array(1, 5, 7))));
```

Comment: This works for integers but doesn't seem to work on string values.

Comment: It should work just fine for strings as well. What does the generated query look like?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Cake.  I can't seem to find how to easily print out the generated query.  I changed the ints to 'test', 'test2' and I'm getting the error: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'test' in 'where clause'

Comment: Set debug to 2 in `config/core.php`, look at the bottom of the page. And the error indicates an error in your query, you seem to be searching for the field `test`, which does not exist.

Comment: Ah, was doing 'id', array(...) instead of 'id' => array(...)